# Cocoapods install

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

When I try to install Cocoapods or update gem on Mavericks (10.9.1) I keep getting the following and I am unable to find a resolution.  Here's the error:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in
>   `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a
>   simple key at line 2 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)    from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in`
>   parse_stream'    from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in
>   `parse'   from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in`
>   load'    from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:318:in
>   `load_file'   from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:191:in`
>   initialize'  from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in
>   `new'     from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in`
>   do_configuration'    from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in
>   `run'     from /usr/bin/gem:21:in`'

Comment: Please refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73307243/cocoapods-not-found-by-flutter)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like incompatibility between your system ruby version and the version of cocoapods you are trying to install.

I highly recommend that you install **rvm** to handle ruby versioning on your mac.

- https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Once rvm is installed try running running:

```
$ gem install cocoapods
```

**rvm** can handle multiple ruby versions that are per user on your system. If you've been using sudo everytime you run your ruby commands **rvm** is also your answer.