# CocoaPods not found by Flutter

Tags: ruby, flutter, rubygems, cocoapods

I have successfully (re)installed them, with

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods && sudo gem install cocoapods`

But they are not found by Flutter (`flutter doctor` keeps giving `CocoaPods not installed`).

It might be because of two different Ruby versions.

The executable `pod` is not found indeed...(`which pod`)

Relevant executables are:

- ruby 3.1.2 is in /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin/sandbox-pod.
- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin/pod

My Bash setup file has:

```
# Ruby
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Any idea?

Ps: I am on [macOS v12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (executable `brew`) fixes the issue:

Remember to run `brew link --overwrite cocoapods`.