# cocoapods-generate not installed when cocoapods installed via Homebrew?

Tags: gradle, rubygems, cocoapods, homebrew, kotlin-multiplatform

I am using M2 Mac and using Kotlin Multiplatform and Flutter.

Since Cocopads from  `gem install cocoapads` needs FFi and run along with `arch -x86_64` , which is not possible when gradle scripts automatically running `pod install` by themselves,

I installed it via homebrew

But now the problem is, in order to use a pod library in gradle from a Kotlin Multiplatform project (inside `Cocoapods { ... }` ) , the gradle script is running `pod gen`, a utility from [Cocoapods-Generate](https://github.com/square/cocoapods-generate) .

But the problem is, this Cocoapods-Generate not found in brew's cocoapods installation, because it is listed in Gem Repo only

So whats now happening now is,

If I install cocoapods via Gem , gradle building failed due to Arch mismatch problem. Whereas if I install via homebrew, cocoapods-generate not installed and `pod gen` command executed by gradle scripts failing.

So I can't find how to resolve this issue. Please help me.

Comment: Please refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73307243/cocoapods-not-found-by-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues. I think everybody's gratefully abandoning cocoapods in favour of Swift packages. There's a [Kotlin SPM plugin](https://github.com/PaGr0m/kotlin-spm-plugin), hopefully that makes KMM viable.